# Does an off the shelf electromechanical device exist that does rotary oscillations

Tags: motors, torque, stepper-motor, actuator

Does an off the shelf electromechanical device exist that does rotary oscillations?

Similar to a torsion pendulum motion or a rotary spring but gets some energy supplied by electrical means to help keep it going? I do not mean an electric motor that can reverse direction as I do not want the motor to directly have to fight the current direction of angular momentum. Maybe it's something like a scotch yoke on an electric motor (however that is linear oscillator motion and I want it to be circular around a central axis - probably not exceeding 360 degrees).

If such an off the shelf device or mechanism does exist, what is it called?

Comment: Use the motor, disc and pin from a scotch yoke to drive the load directly. Omit the sliding part of the yoke.

Comment: An electric motor, with appropriate drive circuitry, would not "fight the current direction of" rotation.  It could, in fact, be exactly what you need.  Could you please _edit your question_ with more information -- describing what you're actually trying to do with be best, but telling us what sort of torque you want to supply, at what frequency, whether you're supplying a spring, what the moment of inertia is and whether this device needs to suspend any mass will all -- partially -- suffice.